# horizonatal line (hr) on sides of nav bar twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a line

---

on the sides of a transparent navbar whose items are centered in the middle of the page. 
I'm only looking for boostrap specific answers

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-transparent navbar-static>
    <div class = "navbar-inner"> 
        <div class ="container">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"data-toggle="collapse"        data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div> 
            <hr>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Brand </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of container -->
    </div><!-- end of navbar-inner -->
</nav> <!-- end of navbar -->
```

Comment: have you tried adding a selector to container class ?

Comment: yes. Got it after playing around, seems as though the <hr> has changed in html5 and you have to override twitter bootstraps hr style